# Embed UITableView/UICollectionView in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I am trying to build a two-dimensional navigation in an app, similar to what Snapchat has done. See picture below for reference of what I am trying to achieve. I tried to do this by putting all views inside of a `UIScrollView` and then manually creating direction locks to restrict it to never be able to scroll onto the empty, top left, area. The idea came from [here](http://bogdanconstantinescu.com/blog/proper-direction-lock-for-uiscrollview.html). This does the job to some extent, but the `UITableView` is not cooperating with the `UIScrollView` very much, and it seems as though they fight for the ownership of touches. I can only scroll the table view after selecting one of its rows first, and I need to touch outside of the table view in order to scroll back to the right.

I know that embedding `UITableViews` inside `UIScrollViews` is [not recommended](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview) by Apple, perhaps even discouraged:

> Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in
>   UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result
>   because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly
>   handled.

But I do not see another way to achieve this. I have also tried using two separate `UIScrollViews`, one for horizontal scrolling and the other one would be embedded in the first one and control all vertical scrolling. I had issues setting this up, though, as one of the views would render its subviews rather weird.

If there only was a way to disable a `UIScollView`'s horizontal or vertical pan gesture recognizer... I have also tried setting the `UIScrollView`'s `delaysTouchesBegan` and `canCancelContentTouches` to different values, without any luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a `UIPageViewController` for your horizontal paging, and then a `UITableView` or `UIScrollView` for your vertical content, if a Snapchat-esque effect is what you're after.